# How to create installer for ASP.NET Core windows service?

Tags: asp.net-core, installation, windows-services, windows-installer

I want to create installer that will install my ASP.Net Core 3.1 app as windows service (the app code already has `.UseWindowsService();`).
Right now when i publish the app, there are a lot of files and i just use `sc create` command in cmd to install it as service (specifying .exe path).

I want to create just one exe file that will include installer and files needed for installation. I would like to have some basic ui where you could choose path if you want different path than default. It should start service after installation and set it to start automatically. Before installation it should check if service is already installed and if it is, try to start it and inform user about it.

Answer (score 0):

The  located at https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials will handle this.  Build your EXE to not require .net core.  If you want to install .net core as a prereq instead you'll want to use the IsWiX bootstrapper project template and add .net core to your bundle.wxs.

This short video shows the whole process that's described in the tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxbcPnjfzIc